# how rename file name of random file in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

**I have form with dynamic file upload:**

```
var ordinaryPropertyValue = new Catalog.Core.Entities.OrdinaryPropertyValue();
var fileFile = Request.Files["File" + prop.Id];

if (fileFile == null) continue;

string pathFile = Server.MapPath("~/temp");
string filenameFile = Path.GetFileName(fileFile.FileName);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filenameFile)) {
    fileFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(pathFile, filenameFile));
    ordinaryPropertyValue.Value = Path.Combine(pathFile, filenameFile);
    instance.SetPropertyValue(prop.Id, ordinaryPropertyValue);
}
```

**How can I rename files which are submiited from users?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set file name you want in this line

```
String filenameFile = "MyFile.ext";
String pathFile = Server.MapPath("~/temp/" + filenameFile);
fileFile.SaveAs(pathFile);
```

this will save your file in path `~/temp/MyFile.ext`

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189991/how-rename-file-name-of-random-file-in-mvc) _italic_ **bold** ` I have change this part of code, but it still doesn't work: string pathFile = Server.MapPath("~/temp"); string filenameFile = "p" + prop.Id; if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filenameFile)) { fileFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(pathFile, filenameFile));`